# send data as array inside array using gson in android(all data is dynamic)

Tags: android, arrays, web-services, parsing, gson

Hi i have to send data to server in this format(see below) how i can achieve this please help me. all data is dynamic. May be I have to make pojo first, for sections i have to make another pojo that pojo should be dynamic, then i will have have to make one more pojo for fields. please any one explain how i can send data to server like this I am very confused.

```
{
  "formId": "335",
  "productId": "3001",
  "sections": [
    {
      "id": "690",
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "1953",
          "value": "Mona"
        },
        {
          "id": "1952",
          "value": "Sona"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "692",
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "1956",
          "value": "Vaibhav"
        },
        {
          "id": "1957",
          "value": "Kaup"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "691",
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "1954",
          "value": "banglore"
        },
        {
          "id": "1955",
          "value": "male"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "697",
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "1970",
          "value": "AddressProof",
          "image": "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"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "userCode": "007",
  "appId": "131",
  "appVersion": "131",
  "imeiNumber": "131"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to send the data? And if so; what have you tried?

Comment: ya i have sent data using restclient in which i have to send data as key value pair only, never face this pojo concept

Comment: @android http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/   will helpfull..

Answer (score 0):

Extremely simplified:

```
class Field {
    String id;
    String value;
    String image;
}

class Section {
    String id;
    Field[] fields;
}

class Form {
    String formId;
    String productId;
    String userCode;
    String appId;
    String appVersion;
    String imeiNumber;

    Section[] sections;
}
```

And then serialize it:

```
public static void main(String[] arr) {
    // populate pojo's
    Form form = ....;

    String json = new Gson().toJson(form);
}
```

Comment: ok got it but i have to send this all data to server how it is possible in android before this i was sending data using json easily. And one more thing this section pojo should be dynamic

Comment: it is, I gave you everything you need to make it work, if you have a specific problem edit your question.

Comment: ya sure see i have class called restclient like this:-public void addParam(String key, String value){
    
    try {
     data.put(key, value);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
 
    
   }

Comment: and whenever i have to send data to server i will use method addparam first then there is one class called Asynctask in which I have method doInBackground, in this method i m using restclient and addparam, and in activity's on create I am calling execute method to send data to server.

Comment: I got your idea about creating pojo's like above now my 1st question to you how I create dynamic pojo because that feilds and section portion I am getting from server and I have parsed all data using json array or jsonObject based on this In my app sections and feilds are creating dynamically now I have send sections data and fields data to server then tell how should I resolve? I know you are expert and experienced person but I am not, I am new in android Please help me

Comment: I have one button BUYNOW shold I call this function means String json = new Gson().toJson(form); on click of this button

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class Form {
    private String formId;
    // other fields ....
    private List<Section> sections;
}


public class Section {
    private String id;
    private List<Map<String, String>> fields;
}
```

finally serialize

```
String json = gson.toJson(form);
```